# SynchronizationContext.Post not working inside BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, backgroundworker, synchronizationcontext

I'm using a background-worker to do all of my processing. Inside there, I have many places where I write to my "log" text box. All of those work great, but at the end of the background-worker, the very last line, I have one more call via `SynchronizationContext` that doesn't fire. Why do all of the other calls work, and not the last one?

I should add that the application just "hangs", and there's even an EventLog entry saying:

```
The program MVST.CodeSync.exe version 2.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed.
To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 1f5c
 Start Time: 01ccc0e2e7ca1d42
 Termination Time: 16
 Application Path: C:\Users\ganders\Desktop\NewCodeSync\MVST.CodeSync.exe
 Report Id: 629f3533-2cd6-11e1-9e15-005056b75254
```

Here's the `DoWork` method (which is executed when calling `RunWorkerAsync`):

```
private void bgw_StartCompare(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    OnWriteLogArgs args = null;
    CompareData compareData = e.Argument as CompareData;

    // We need to iterate through all of the nodes and if they are checked, continue
    foreach (TreeNode subSystemNode in compareData.TreeNodes)
    {
        if (!subSystemNode.Checked)
            continue;

        args = new OnWriteLogArgs(String.Format("-------------------------- Comparing sub-system: \"{0}\" with CompareType: \"{1}\" --------------------------", subSystemNode.Text, compareData.CompareType));
        syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(args); }, null);

        // Each of these nodes should be a server, so continue
        foreach (TreeNode serverNode in subSystemNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (!serverNode.Checked)
                continue;

            args = new OnWriteLogArgs(String.Format("-------------------------- Comparing server: \"{0}\" with CompareType: \"{1}\" --------------------------", serverNode.Text, compareData.CompareType));
            syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(args); }, null);

            // The "tag" contains the server information that we need to do the comparison
            CustomConfig.Server server = (CustomConfig.Server)serverNode.Tag;

            if (!compareData.DoneInitialCompare)
                CompareAll(compareData, server, string.Empty, server.CompareBasePath, serverNode, compareData.CompareType);
            else
                CompareAllByTreeNode(compareData, server, serverNode, compareData.CompareType);
        }
    }

    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(new OnWriteLogArgs("Finished the compare...")); }, null);

    RebuildTreeViewArgs rArgs = new RebuildTreeViewArgs(compareData.OnlyShowDifferences, compareData.TreeNodes);
    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnRebuildTreeView(rArgs); }, null);

    MessageBox.Show("It made it...");

    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(new OnWriteLogArgs("Finished calling the rebuild tree view method...")); }, null);
}
```

You'll notice at the end of the `foreach` loop, I do my write that says `Finished the compare...`, and that DOES write, but the next sync call:

```
     syncContext.Post(delegate { OnRebuildTreeView(rArgs); }, null);
```

Never gets executed. Here's that method:

```
private void OnRebuildTreeView(RebuildTreeViewArgs args)
{
    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(new OnWriteLogArgs("Made it to the OnRebuildTreeView method...")); }, null);

    while (bgw.IsBusy)
    {
        syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(new OnWriteLogArgs("Sleeping...")); }, null);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    syncContext.Post(delegate { OnWriteLog(new OnWriteLogArgs("Starting the rebuild of the TreeView...")); }, null);

    TreeNode[] tn = args.NewStructure;

    tvSync.Nodes.Clear();

    foreach (TreeNode node in tn)
        tvSync.Nodes.Add(node);

    foreach (TreeNode node in tvSync.Nodes)
        FixCheckedAndUnCheckedNodes(node);

    ReloadTreeView(args.OnlyShowDifferences);
}
```

Comment: why do you keep calling the `syncContext` inside `OnRebuildTreeView` if it is already running in the GUI thread?, also your `Thread.Sleep` call is going to freeze the GUI thread which is not a good idea at all.. I don't know if these are making your application hang but they don't look good. Also `.Post` does NOT block the caller, if you r logic need to block use `.Send` instead

Comment: Good point, didn't think about doing the syncContext call from the OnRebuildTreeView method...I'll take that out. As far as the Thread.Sleep(), I just added that just in case...(more debugging tries). I'll remove that stuff and try again. Thanks

Comment: It might make things simpler if you attach `OnRebuildTreeView` to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, from your code it seems like you only want to execute that once the main method of your thread finishes.

Comment: I guess your `syncContext` refers to the UI thread. I think you should use the [`ReportProgress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method and [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event instead. Have you tried stepping through the method in debug mode? Then you'll see which method hangs.

Comment: Matthias, I didn't do that because inside the CompareAll() and CompareByTreeNode() methods (which are called from the DoWork() method that I showed above), there are threads started for each individual file that is being compared. So the backgroundworker is running, as well as 1 thread for every file in a directory. I thought that that would have caused confusion, but maybe not. It took me about 10 hours to re-write this utility to be multi-threaded, not sure how eager I am to go back and "try" that configuration.

Comment: I have another question about this utility; how much threading is too much? Right now, my backgroundworker initiates everything, and then there is a thread started for each file in a directory (6 files in a folder, 6 threads will be started). What if I implemented multiple threads for each folder level? Would the OS have a problem with that? That could begin to be 100's of threads all running at the same time. By the way, this program, obviously, uses recursion to sync the files from the my build server to my host server...

Comment: Matthias, it is now working after I removed the syncContext call from the OnRebuildTreeView method. How do I give you props?

Comment: Now that I have all of the regular threading working, I wanted to take it a step further and do more threads per server because it's still not fast enough ("syncing" my entire code base to our deployment servers still takes almost 3 hours). To recap, I have the program spin up a thread for each file in a particular directory. I tried spinning up a new thread for each directory in a directory, but that HAMMERED the CPU and I think the OS got confused on which threads went where....so. Now I would like to add a new thread for each server. So when I try and sync each sub-system, it will do...

Comment: all servers at the same time. The problem that I'm running into is, it looks like the OS is still getting confused on which results go to which server. ie (server1 is in sync, server2 is flagged as needing to copy all contents, and server3 is in sync. My results will show only server3 needs the contents copied over). Is it possible that I have too much threading going on that the OS can't handle all of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show("It made it...");
```

may also be causing problems. as this is expecting the UI thread, when in fact, your on a background thread

Comment: I added that in for debugging purposes (to see if it really got to that line). I just took it out and it still doesn't write the message that is right after it...

Comment: Use [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) for debugging purpose. Methods that imply ui are evil for debugging multi-threaded applications.